# delete of instant search content with the delete of keyword

Tags: javascript, search

so i have search function with jquery to display instantly the content of what i search it is simple one here is the code:

```
function searchq() {
  var searchTxt = $("input[name='search']") .val();
  $.post("search.php", {searchVal: searchTxt}, function(output){
   $("#output").html(output);
  });
}
```

I use php for backend

```
<?php
$nonavbar = '';
include "init.php";

$output = '';
if (isset($_POST['searchVal'])) {
  $searchq = $_POST['searchVal'];
  //$searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $searchq);
  $stmt3 = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM novel WHERE NovelName LIKE '%$searchq%'");
  $stmt3->execute();
  $rows = $stmt3->fetchAll();
  $count = $stmt3->rowCount();
  if ($count == 0) {
    $output = "there is no search results!";
  }else{
  foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $fname = $row['NovelName'];

     $output .= "<div>
        <ul>
          <li>" . $fname .  "</li>
        </ul>
     </div>";
  }
  }
}
 echo ($output);
?>
```

and this is the html form for search

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="search novelname.." onkeydown="searchq()">
 </form>

<div id="output" class="searchresult"></div>
```

everythong is work fine but I need to add function for delete the result when user delete the keywords for search bar honstly i didnt know much about javascript but the search work fine andi need to add this function plz help and thank

Comment: So, something like `if (searchText === '') $('#output').hide() else $('#output').show()`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of onkeydown use onblur event

```
<input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="search novelname.." onblur="searchq()">
```

To clear the output use the method like below,and same funtion will work for onkeydown as well, but it is better to use blur event instead of onkeydown.

```
function searchq() {
  var searchTxt = $("input[name='search']").val();
  if(!searchTxt) { $("#output").html(""); return;  }
  $.post("search.php", {searchVal: searchTxt}, function(output){
   $("#output").html(output);
  });
}
```

Comment: The problem with using onkeydown straight, is that you'll be hammering the server with a  request per keystroke. Another solution is to just throttle your keydown events, making it so a request isn't sent until an event hasn't fired for, maybe half a second.

Comment: Yes, that's y its better to use onblur event instead of onkeydown. iIf you still want to use onkeydown, write the code inside of set timeout function. so that it request will be not a every keystroke. try to give some 50 - 100 ms.

Comment: @Tamilmani the if condition didn't work at all and when I change onkeydown to onblur also didn't work